# Spring Security: session.invalidate() vs invalidate-session="true"

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

What's the difference between the two? I'm not so sure but I believe the HttpServletReqest.getSession.invalidate() invalidates the user's session only while the  invalidate-session="true" invalidates the session and redirects the user to the defined session-expired page. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I would want to understand this more. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invalidate-session` is an attribute on the `<logout>` element and causes the session to be invalidated upon logout (which is the default behavior), but doesn't cauese any redirection itself.

The session-expired page comes into picture if a request contains an invalid/expired session id, in which case the `SessionManagementFilter` redirects it to a pre-configured URL, which you can set through the `<session-management invalid-session-url="...">` configuration. In case nothing is set, no redirection happens.

`HttpServletReqest.getSession.invalidate()` simply invalidates the session, as you said.